# Support both jsp and jspx in spring 3.0

Tags: jsp, spring-mvc, spring-roo, spring-3, jspx

i've set up a roo application. The default view resolver built-in in roo is for jspx files. Is it possible to support also jsp files?. I tried configuring two viewResolvers but it seems that no urlBasedViewResolvers can coexist, its either one or the other.

Changing the order does not affect the behaviour. If I set order =1 to the jspx then if i search for any .jsp file it gives me 404. The same if I search for jspx but jsp viewResolver is set with order =1.

Is there anyway to do this? Thanks!

here is my webmvc-config.xml

```
<bean id="viewResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver">
        <property name="order" value="1"/>
        <property name="viewClass"
            value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView" />
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jspx" />
    </bean>
    <bean id="jspViewResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
                <property name="order" value="2"/>
        <property name="viewClass"
            value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView" />
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </bean>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One probably not a good solution that I can think of is to not provide a suffix, and to explicitly specify the .jsp or .jspx suffix when returning a view name.

```
<bean id="jspViewResolver"
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
            <property name="order" value="2"/>
    <property name="viewClass"
        value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView" />
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
    <property name="suffix" value="" />
</bean>
```

and when returning a view name:

```
return "myview.jsp";
return "myview.jspx";
```

OR

Another solution if you know the name pattern for your jsp and jspx views names will be to provide the view names as one more parameter to one of the resolvers:

```
<bean id="jspViewResolver"
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
            <property name="order" value="2"/>
    <property name="viewClass"
        value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView" />
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
    <property name="suffix" value="jsp" />
    <property name="viewNames">
        <list>
    <value>view1*</view>
    <value>view2*</view>
    <value>view3*</view>
    </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

If this viewresolver returns a null if it does not match any of the view patterns it would then go to your jspx view resolver.

Comment: the second approach did the trick, though, i've to manually enter view names, not a big deal.