# I can get Spring to render either jspxs or jsps but not both. Can this be done?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-roo, jspx

This is my servlet-context.xml

```
<beans:bean id="jspxResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <beans:property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
    <beans:property name="suffix" value=".jspx" />
    <beans:property name="order" value="0"/>
</beans:bean>

<beans:bean id="jspResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <beans:property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
    <beans:property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    <beans:property name="order" value="1"/>
</beans:bean>
```

By changing order I can get the other set of files to render but it will never render both.

I have a tiles setup using some roo taglibs/jspx that I want to redirect error output to and I thought this would be an easy way to make it happen.  Clearly I was wrong about that.

Comment: did you try using 1/2 instead 0/1 or without setting order to `InternalResourceViewResolver`?

Comment: It seems that this one proposed a valid solution, see the second approach : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11603707/support-both-jsp-and-jspx-in-spring-3-0