# How resolve org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver in spring mvc

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

In my application web spring mvc. Problem, I use 2 view(.jsp and jspx). But in servlet-context.xml, i just config for 1 view(.jsp).

```
<beans:bean
     class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <beans:property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
        <beans:property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
 </beans:bean>
```

What is the way resolve use 2 view in an Application spring MVC? Thanks.

Comment: Try solution posted here: 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18215402/spring-mvc-with-multiple-view-resolvers

Comment: similar question posted here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11603707/support-both-jsp-and-jspx-in-spring-3-0

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2288805/2006839 try this solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You add order property in bean tag

```
  <beans:bean
         class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
            <beans:property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
            <beans:property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
            <property name="order" value="1"/>
     </beans:bean>
```